# Scannotation find classes inside ear/war/jar

Tags: jakarta-ee, ear, jboss6.x

My application is running under JBoss AS 6.

If the application was deployed exploded, scannotation find classes successfuly. But if the application is deployed archived in a EAR, that contains an WAR, that contains a JAR, scannotation can't scan my classes.

> FileNotFoundException: /opt/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/icob.ear/icob-web.war/WEB-INF/lib/vraptor-3.3.2-SNAPSHOT.jar (Not a directory)

How I should proceed?